# How in azure function bind event hub output parameter via attributes

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I want to bind input and output parameters from and to event hub using attributes.

In a documentation there is only information how to bind to output using `return` statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---c-example

`[FunctionName("EventHubOutput")]
    [return: EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
    public static string Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        return $"{DateTime.Now}";
    }`

But I want to use `ICollector<EventData> outputEventHub` as a parameter to have something as below

```
[FunctionName("EventHubRewriter")]
public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection ="EventHubInputConnectionAppSetting")] EventData[] inputMessages, ICollector<EventData> outputMessages, TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

**How to generate binding using attributes for the output event hub?**

Update:
Here is an info how function.json is gnerated for attribute binding: [function.json generation](http://Here%20is%20an%20info%20how%20function.json%20is%20generated%20for%20attribute%20binding:%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#conversion-to-functionjson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost exactly the same:

```cs
[EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] 
ICollector<EventData> outputMessages
```

The full signature:

```cs
[FunctionName("EventHubRewriter")]
public static void Run(
    [EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection ="EventHubInputConnectionAppSetting")] 
    EventData[] inputMessages, 
    [EventHub("outputEventHubMessage", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
    ICollector<EventData> outputMessages, 
    TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought it is like that. But after deploy it generates me function.json as below:
`
    {
        "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-1.0.6",
        "configurationSource": "attributes",
        "bindings": [
        {
           "type": "eventHubTrigger",
           "connection": "EventHubInputConnectionAppSetting",
           "path": "output",
           "name": "eventDataSet"
        }
       ],
      "disabled": false,
      "scriptFile": "../bin/EventHub.dll",
      "entryPoint": "EventHub.Ordered.Run"
    }
`

Comment: @wolszakp That's ok. Input/Output bindings are not included into auto-generated `function.json`

Comment: Ok thanks for an explanation.
But what's a reason to use this attributes - I thought that thanks to this attributes `function.json` will be automatically generated.

Comment: @wolszakp Runtime will use the attribute directly, skipping `function.json` sectuon

Comment: I meant what is in documentation:
Ok thanks for an explanation.
But what's a reason to use this attributes - I thought that thanks to this attributes `function.json` will be automatically generated.
I am pointing what is in documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output---c-script-example

Comment: Thanks it works.
I think that it is misleading that sometimes binding in `function.json` are needed and sometimes they are inbuilt in dll.

Comment: @wolszakp I agree

Comment: However thanks for your help and explanation. It saves my times