# How to set systemProperties on an EventHub out bindings in an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

Here's my Azure pipeline:

IoTHub → EventHub src → Azure Function in JavaScript → EventHub dest

In the Azure Function, I need to apply some transformation on the event body received as input and put this transformed event in the destination EventHub.

Through the `context.bindingData.systemPropertiesArray`, I'm able to retrieve essential metadata like the `iothub-connection-device-id`:

```js
module.exports = async function (context, messageBodies) {
   messageBodies.forEach((messageBody, index) => {
        const transformedMessageBody = transform(messageBody)
        const deviceId = context.bindingData.systemPropertiesArray[index]['iothub-connection-device-id']
        context.log(deviceId)

        // here I can only set the messageBody. What's the way to attach back the original systemProperties?
        context.bindings.eventHubDest = transformedMessageBody
    })
}
```

**Problem**: the `systemProperties` are lost in the destination EventHub, because I can find a way to set them back inside the Azure Function code:

Source EventHub event:

```
   {
      body: { foo: 'bar' },
      properties: undefined,
      offset: '143360',
      sequenceNumber: 392,
      enqueuedTimeUtc: 2020-02-21T11:30:32.294Z,
      partitionKey: undefined,
      systemProperties: {
        'iothub-connection-device-id': 'qux',
        'iothub-connection-auth-method': '{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}',
        'iothub-connection-auth-generation-id': '637177867069071846',
        'iothub-enqueuedtime': 1582284632134,
        'iothub-message-source': 'Telemetry'
      }
    }
```

Destination EventHub event:

```
   {
      body: { foo: 'transformedBar' },
      properties: undefined,
      offset: '34',
      sequenceNumber: 456,
      enqueuedTimeUtc: 2020-02-21T11:30:33.256Z,
      partitionKey: undefined,
      systemProperties: undefined
   }
```

Note: I'm aware that I could "cheat" and attach the deviceId in the body of the new event,
but I need this value cleanly separated in `systemProperties` for further handling down the line.

Answer (score 1):

This (`context.bindings.eventHubDest = transformedMessageBody`) only sets the message body of the messages that gets sent out. This is a completely new message, not just forwarding the incoming one. Hence, any metadata is lost as well.

Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=csharp#output) it sounds like you cannot bind to `EventData` when using Javascript - as [you can when using C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866413/1537195) Binding to EventData enables you to also set metadata, versus binding to the body string does not.

So I guess if you need that, you need to use C# (Java might also work). Or use something completely different such as Azure Stream Analytics.

Comment: I tried an a C# Azure function. `SystemProperties` are also lost even without touching the input events. So as Serkant Karaca says, `SystemProperties` from the input events have to be copied to the output binding `Properties`.

Comment: that's why I wrote "This is a completely new message, not just forwarding the incoming one". But Serkant is correct that you can only set "application/user-defined properties", not the system properties

Answer (score 1):

SystemProperties cannot be set on the Event Hubs publisher because it is for service use only. I am not sure how it is done in JS trigger however you should use eventData.properties bag instead.