# SystemProperties not populated for Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-iot-hub

We have recently upgraded our Service Fabric service that reads messages from Azure IoT Hub built-in Event Hub from the deprecated Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs SDK to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs SDK (following this [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/MigrationGuide.md)).

We are running into an issue where the SystemProperties for the [EventData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet) class are not fully populated. Specifically, *message-id*, *correlation-id*, and *user-id* properties come in with no data, as seen here:

> {"message-id":{},"user-id":{"Length":0,"IsEmpty":true},"correlation-id":{},"iothub-connection-device-id":"xxxxxxx","iothub-connection-auth-method":"{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}","iothub-connection-auth-generation-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","iothub-enqueuedtime":"2023-07-13T22:00:53.501Z","iothub-message-source":"Telemetry","x-opt-sequence-number":4785508,"x-opt-offset":1005023123136,"x-opt-enqueued-time":"2023-07-13T22:00:53.652+00:00"}

We are using an [EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient?view=azure-dotnet) with the *AmqpTcp* transport type.

Can anyone help us in determining why these system properties are not being populated? This worked previously with the deprecated SDK.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could share the link of the deprecated SDK for the system properties you have gone referred to(or) the code you used? could tell me are trying to change the system properties of Azure Event hub or Azure Iothub –

Comment: How to set the System Properties of ["EventData"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/366)

Comment: send a message with the desired Systemproperties message-id, correlation-id, and user-id to Azure.Messaging.EventHubs [Output](https://i.imgur.com/2cDLXBG.png)

Comment: properties are only populated for events received from the Event Hubs service. The set is otherwise [empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.systemproperties?view=azure-dotnet#remarks)

Comment: Thank you @Sampath, very helpful! I have marked your answer as accepted as this helped me understand why these system properties were not populated. I am also adding an answer regarding a related issue I found that was contributing to this, as we had some custom properties that also failed to populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.systemproperties?view=azure-dotnet#remarks) the events that are received through the Event Hubs service have these characteristics filled. The events received from other sets empty.

```cs
 static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromEventHub()
    {
        await using var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, connectionString, eventHubName);
          await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync())
        {
            EventData eventData = partitionEvent.Data;
            object messageId = eventData.Properties["message-id"];
            object correlationId = eventData.Properties["correlation-id"];
            object userId = eventData.Properties["user-id"];
            object Iotubconectiondevidid = eventData.Properties["iothub - connection - device - id"];
            object iothubconnectionauthmethod = eventData.Properties["iothub - connection - auth - method"];
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-non-telemetry-event-schema.md) for Missing IoT Hub System [Properties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go/issues/160)  and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60338607/how-to-set-systemproperties-on-an-eventhub-out-bindings-in-an-azure-function).

**Event From Iot Hub:**

[image]

**Event from Event Hubs:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally for anyone who encounters this issue, I also discovered a related issue to my original problem in that we were using some custom properties (with [EventData.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.properties?view=azure-dotnet)) that were also not being populated.

Turns out that the Properties Dictionary keys are case-sensitive, where before we upgraded to System.Messaging.EventHubs they were not. I know this because I had two sets of devices sending messages to Azure IoT Hub (one used all lower-case property keys and one that used case-sensitive property keys) and they both worked correctly prior to the upgrade.

Tweaking my code that retrieves these property values to retrieve by case-insensitive keys fixed the issue, along with the other accepted answer by @Sampath.